# Lightning component iteration through a list into a table with set number of columns

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Simple question but I'm sure there's a much easier way.

So I iterate through a list and right now they're each on their own row. But how would I put the values into columns of, for example 3?

For example if we have 9 values, it'd look like this:

x x x

x x x

x x x

and if we had 5 values, it'd look like this:

x x x

x x

Comment: Do you want to change the form of the items being displayed?

Comment: No just that it goes to a new row every 3rd item

Comment: You can use the lightning:layout and lightning:layoutItem to accomplish that

Comment: Is there any way to do it with table?

Comment: I don't know that a table would be an effective way to display it. A table shows tabular data, each row represents an item and the columns are used to track attributes on the item (fields), by using a table you're breaking that and ruining the user experience in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve by tweak u r styles, i just used `slds-grid slds-wrap` and `slds-size--1-of-3 slds-p-horizontal_x-small`

**cmp**

```
<aura:attribute name="nineItems" type="List" default="['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']" />
<aura:attribute name="fiveItems" type="List" default="['1','2','3','4','5']" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<lightning:card title="Nine Items">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.nineItems}" var="item" indexVar="index">
        <div class="slds-size--1-of-3 slds-p-horizontal_x-small">{!item}</div>

    </aura:iteration>    
</div>
</lightning:card>
<lightning:card title="Five Items">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.fiveItems}" var="item" indexVar="index">
        <div class="slds-size--1-of-3 slds-p-horizontal_x-small">{!item}</div>

    </aura:iteration>    
</div>
</lightning:card>
```

please upvote/accept if solution works, and let me know if had any issue with this solution
[image]